# Can I submit papers already published on arXiv to Communications of the ACM (CACM)?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, open-access, acm

Recently I already published a paper on arXiv. I want to enrich and submit the paper to Communications of the ACM (CACM). But as mentioned in [Author Guidelines of CACM (Section 5 ACM Policies)](https://cacm.acm.org/about-communications/author-center/author-guidelines/#5):

> Articles that have been submitted simultaneously to other magazines or journals will be declined outright and not reconsidered.

So is it possible to submit the paper already published on arXiv?
Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, because arXiv is a preprint server and not a journal or magazine.